# Synchronization: What is wrong in my code?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I am reading about synchronization [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html). Then I wrote this program

```
public class Counter {

    int i = 0;

    public synchronized void increment() {
        System.out.println("inc called");
        i++;
        System.out.println("inc exited");
    }

    public synchronized void decrement() {
        System.out.println("dec called");
        i--;
        System.out.println("dec exited");
    }

    public synchronized void print(String name) {
        System.out.println(name + " " + i);
    }

}

public class UnsynchronizedCounterTest implements Runnable {

    private Counter counter = new Counter();

    public UnsynchronizedCounterTest(String name) {
        Thread t = new Thread(this, name);
        t.start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        UnsynchronizedCounterTest test = new UnsynchronizedCounterTest(
                "New Thread 1");
        test.callMe();
    }

    public void callMe() {
        counter.decrement();
        counter.print("main thread");
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        counter.increment();
        counter.print("another thread");
    }
}
```

When I run this program I get below outputs

```
dec called
dec exited
inc called
inc exited
another thread 0
main thread 0

dec called
dec exited
main thread -1
inc called
inc exited
another thread 0
```

I believe that the first output is wrong. I dont know what is wrong in my program. Can anyone please correct me.

Comment: change the title from 'sunchronization' to 'synchronization'

Comment: Why do you think the first output is wrong?

Comment: By the way, you might find this article on different approaches to synchronization interesting: http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue215.html

Comment: @nhahtdh The output should be -1, 0 or 1, 0. If main thread executes first then it decrements i which is -1, then the new thread increments i which is 0. If the new thread runs first it increments i which is 1, then the main thread runs and decrements i which is 0. Because they are synchronized methods. I will only get those outputs. But 0, 0 is not an expected output. One or the other thread is interfering with other.

Comment: @KrishnaChaitanya: Each of the operations inc and dec and print are synchronized, but the sequence inc-print and dec-print in run() and callMe are not.

Comment: @cdshines No I dont want to learn new techniques right now. I first want to understand it properly from what is mentioned in the standard java documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following code:

```
    counter.decrement();
    counter.print("main thread");
```

is dangerous. While it in 99% prints the correct value of `Counter.i`, sometimes another thread can wedge in the gap between the first and second method calls. Better print the value inside decrement and increment methods. If you want just to print without changing the value, just the same use synchronized method or block, to avoid printing stale value.

The outputs correspond to your program - if you think they are wrong, you program is wrong also. Please explain what you want.

Comment: Okay, I understood. So what should I do to get the second output always. I removed synchronized for all the methods in my Counter class and, I surround the method calls in `run` and `callMe` with synchronized, then I get the expected output. I hope this is another alternative. Am I right?

Comment: if you want to get always the same output, run all the task in a single thread. If you want to make strict order on several threads, the result will be that each moment only one thread is running - you have no performance gain but only complexity of program.

Answer (score 4):

The first output is correct, because the locks are granular to method calls.

Your output describes the plausible execution which justifies your output:

1. `main` calls `dec()`, grabs the lock, decrements, exits, releases the lock;
2. `other` calls `inc()`; grabs the lock, increments, exits, releases the lock;
3. `main` calls `print()`; grabs the lock, reads 0, exits, releases the lock;
4. `other` calls `print()`, grabs the lock, reads 0, exits, releases the lock.